# Format decimal for use in XML and ignore culture

Tags: c#, .net, xml

We need to insert decimal values into a XML document (done by a XML writer) which works fine. First we used `XmlConvert.ToString(myDecimalValue)` which printed the value with four digits. Now we are forced to use always two digits and we tried to change this but with no luck so far.

First we dropped the use of `XmlConvert` because we found not overload that allows us to format the decimal so we tried `myDecimalValue.ToString("0.00")` which prints only two digits but replaces the `.` with a `,` which is not valid in our case.

**So how can we format a decimal like `25000.00m` to a string like `25000.00`? (Rounding does not matter because the values never have more then two digits set)**

**EDIT**

```
decimal m_nAmt;
public decimal Amount
{
    get
    {
        return m_nAmt;
    }
    set
    {
        if ((value < 0M) || (value > 999999999.99M))
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }
        if (SepaUtil.DecimalPlaces(value) > 2)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }

        m_nAmt = value;
    }
}
```

And where is is written

```
// the original method
XmlConvert.ToString(m_nAmt);
```

Both methods are member of the same class;

Here is a example of a value written into the Xml file

```
<InstdAmt Ccy="EUR">3360.0000</InstdAmt>
```

- A important note is, that this is part of class library which covers parts of the SEPA standard but the author does not provide any support.*

**Edit 2**

*A example where a node get written. I used the Immediate window to get the current value of the `ControlSum` Property (System.Decimal) and the value written by `XmlConvert`. The result is that `XmlConvert` does write four decimal places although I cannot confirm that when using `XmlConvert` with a decimal variable in LINQPad. Where one difference is that this library uses .net 2.0*

[image]

**My Conclusion & Solution**

It seems that the `XmlConvert.ToString()` or `decimalvalue.ToString()` applies four decimal places because the original value had four `0` applied which got ignored by the `SepaUtil.DecimalPlaces(value)` check (because `0` get ignored) and are not shown within the "Immediate Window" of VS2012. So I changed

```
 m_nAmt = value;
```

to

```
m_nAmt = Math.Round(value,2);
```

to ensure always two decimal places. This way will add missing decimal places and truncate if there are more.

Comment: As an aside, do you *have* to use `XmlWriter`? Are you writing very large documents? I generally reach for LINQ to XML as a general-purpose solution which is much friendlier than XmlWriter and XmlReader.

Comment: Your question confuses me a little - `XmlConvert.ToString(25000.00m)` already returns "25000.00". Where are you getting four decimal places from?

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, the docs are somethings very large. (for clarification: we are writing SEPA XML files which can contains hundreds or thousands of transactions.)

Comment: You could potentially still create an `XElement` for each transaction and use `element.WriteTo(writer)`. Just something to think about.

Comment: @JonSkeet I edited the question to provided more information on the we used it.

Comment: Your edit still doesn't explain the problem. My guess is that `SepaUtil.DecimalPlaces` doesn't work properly - but as I say, `XmlConvert.ToString(25000.00m)` already does what you want. It's also not clear whether the output has to have *at most* two decimal places or *at least* two decimal places.

Comment: @JonSkeet I see. Well the value set has guaranteed two decimal places (no more, no less -> required by the SEPA standard) At this point I can only guess so I think I will have to dig a little deeper in the library. (My linqPad tests also showed only two decimal places) I will come back with hopefully more information... thanks so far for your help!!

Comment: If the value only has 2 decimal places, then `XmlConvert` isn't going to make up any extra digits. I suggest you try to come up with a short but complete example demonstrating the problem. (Show the code which is actually writing this value to the XmlWriter. Just the ToString call isn't enough.

Comment: @JonSkeet I looked into it by using the immediate Window and can now say, that XmlConvert.ToString() does print four decimal places. I then tested XmlConvert.ToString(Math.Round(thisControlSum,2)) which worked. I guess I have to ensure that all decimal values always have two decimal places to get arround this.

Comment: Well what was the value that converted to 4dp using `XmlConvert`? What happened if you just called `ToString`?

Comment: @JonSkeet If I call `this.ControlSum.ToString()` I ending up with `3360,0000` Basically the same problem, just the `.` is replaced by `,` which would be correct based on the localization but wrong for the SEPA standard :/ dunno why but if there are no decimal places both methods are printing `0000` as decimal places.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming this really is `decimal`, I suggest you round the decimal value *first*:

```
decimal rounded = Math.Round(original, 2);
string roundedText = XmlConvert.ToString(rounded);
```

Obviously you can specify appropriate rounding/truncation behaviour, too.

While you *can* just specify the invariant culture instead as per PMF's answer, I would consider the above to be clearer in what you're trying to achieve:

- You're specifically rounding the value
- You're specifically using an XML conversion

One difference, however - in my version above, if the original number only has one decimal place (or none), you'll end up with (say) "15.5". If you explicitly format the string with the invariant culture, you'll end up with "15.50". If you definitely *always* want exactly 2 decimal places (no fewer) then PMF's answer is a more suitable one.

Comment: Why do you recommend rounding the value?

Comment: @Enigmativity: I posted before the OP claimed there were never more than 2 decimal places. Now it's unclear what the actual problem is...

Comment: I chooses your answer because `Math.Round(value,2)` was the easiest way to ensure two decimal places (maybe value += 0.00m would have worked too but I was tired testing) Anyway all your comments helped me much in solving this issue! Thank you again! See my last edit for my final solution.

Comment: @JJR: I suspect the problem here is the immediate window - I've definitely seen issues where it doesn't display the most helpful form. The Watch window is better. Adding `0.00m` wouldn't have helped - that would ensure *at least* 2DP, but it wouldn't truncate to 2DP.

Comment: Thanks for that advice! I will definitely remember it the next time! But as a word for the immediate window, the values shown there also got written into the XML file. So it was not completely wrong at this time ;) But still the reason why this happens is unknown to me. All ways to reproduce it failed and the author of the lib didn't answered by know. So this behavior seems to be somehow bound to the project.

Comment: @JJR: The result of `XmlConvert.ToString(...)` will be accurate - it's the value of the variable which is the problem. I strongly suspect it was `3360.0000m`, but was showing up in the immediate window as `3360`. *That's* the problem.

Comment: Ahhh, I see. Yes, that may be possible because `SepaUtil.DecimalPlaces(value)` ignores `0`. Awesome! Solved! I will add this to my footnote! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 5):

Use

```
myValue.ToString("0.00", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

This will always write the value in a language-independent format (basically English). Use the same argument in any `Parse()` or `TryParse()` calls when reading.

As a general rule, *all* `Parse()`, `TryParse()` or `ToString()` calls should have the CultureInfo argument specified, either as `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` or `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`. This prevents any strange bugs that happen when the users language uses a different decimal mark than the developers.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this worked but It would require me to change it in the whole project. The easier way was to fix the `Amount` value, by ensuring always to decimal places.

Comment: What about the group separator? If you print numbers as "N" with InvariantCulture, you will get , (comma) as group separator, which might be not what you want for XML. Is group separator ignored for 0.00 ?

Comment: @JustAMartin: Of course, this applies also for the group separator. However, many applications won't use the "N" formatting but use "F" instead, where this problem won't show up. For writting to (computer-readable) files, the "R" option would probably be best.